# Problems with v-for and the :src that point to reactive variable in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a problem inside a v-for, inside this v-for I create several images, which have their src pointing to an object saved in a reactive array.This array is obtained from a fetch that returns this type of objects:

```
{
categoria:"Web"
data:"2018-02-20 00:00:00"
idgaleria:"1"
titol:"Web technologies"
url:"http://www.laqshya.in/images/web1.png"
}
```

And this is the v-for inside the template:

```
<div v-for="entrada in entrades">
   <div class="caption">
        <img src="{{entrada.url}}" alt="" class="pic"/>
   </div>
   <h4>{{entrada.titol}}</h4>
   <p>Publicat el {{entrada.data}}</p>
</div>
```

The result is that the template is rendered without any problem, but the images are not visible, If I look at the browser element inspector, I can see that the image element is rendered as follows

`<img src="'{{entrada.url}}'" alt="" class="pic">`

Does anyone know how to refer to the reactive variable within the src attribute of an image?
I have been searching the internet for the same problem, and I have seen that it happens to more people, but all refer to images that are stored locally and not on the Internet, as is my case.
Thank you!

Comment: Use `:src="entrada.url"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
  <img :src="entrada.url" alt="" class="pic"/>
```

or

```
  <img v-bind:src="entrada.url" alt="" class="pic"/>
```

They are the same, one being the shorthand syntax.  Without it, the contents in the quotes will be interpreted as a string, not code.